# Unwanted line between chunks in heightmap infinite terrain

Tags: lua, heightmap, love2d, noise

I can't figure out what is causing the line between my two chunks.  They are completely aligned.  It must be something to do with the algorithm.  I am using lua with the love2d game engine.  Here is a pic:

[image: line between chunks]

Here is the code:

```
seed = 257
local canvas = love.graphics.newCanvas()

function Interpolate(a, b, x)
    ft = x * 3.1415927
    f = (1 - math.cos(ft)) * 0.5

    return  a*(1-f) + b*f
end

function Noise(x, y)
    n = x + y * seed
    n = bit.bxor((bit.lshift(n,13)),n)
    return ( 1.0 - ( bit.band((n * (n * n * 15731 + 789221) + 
      1376312589), 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0))  
end

function SmoothedNoise1(x, y)
    corners = ( Noise(x-1, y-1)+Noise(x+1, y-1)+Noise(x-1, 
      y+1)+Noise(x+1, y+1) ) / 16
    sides   = ( Noise(x-1, y)  +Noise(x+1, y)  +Noise(x, y-1)  +Noise(x, 
      y+1) ) /  8
    center  =  Noise(x, y) / 4
    return corners + sides + center
end

function InterpolatedNoise_1(x, y)
    integer_X, fractional_X = math.modf(x)
    integer_Y, fractional_Y = math.modf(y)

    v1 = SmoothedNoise1(integer_X,     integer_Y)
    v2 = SmoothedNoise1(integer_X + 1, integer_Y)
    v3 = SmoothedNoise1(integer_X,     integer_Y + 1)
    v4 = SmoothedNoise1(integer_X + 1, integer_Y + 1)

    i1 = Interpolate(v1 , v2 , fractional_X)
    i2 = Interpolate(v3 , v4 , fractional_X)

    return Interpolate(i1 , i2 , fractional_Y)
end

function getExampleMap()
    mapWidth = 400
    mapHeight = 400
    mapMin = InterpolatedNoise_1(0, 0)
    mapMax = mapMin
    map = {}
    amp = 128  
    freq =32 
    octaves = 6 
    for x = 0, mapWidth - 1 do
        map[x] = {}
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            map[x][y] = 0
            for i = 1, octaves do
                map[x][y] = map[x][y] + getNoiseValue(x, y, freq / i, 
                  amp / i)
            end
            mapMin = math.min(mapMin, map[x][y])
            mapMax = math.max(mapMax, map[x][y])
        end
    end
    -- /*scale the values between 0 and 255 for rendering in grey 
      scale.*/
    mapMultiplier = 255 / (mapMax - mapMin)
    for x = 0, mapWidth - 1 do
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            map[x][y] = map[x][y] * mapMultiplier
        end
    end
end

function getExampleMap2()
    mapWidth = 400
    mapHeight = 400
    mapMin = InterpolatedNoise_1(0, 0)
    mapMax = mapMin
    map2 = {}
    amp = 128
    freq =32
    octaves = 6
    for x = 400, (mapWidth + 400) do
        map2[x] = {}
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            map2[x][y] = 0
            for i = 1, octaves do
                map2[x][y] = map2[x][y] + getNoiseValue(x, y, freq / i, 
                  amp / i)

            end
            mapMin = math.min(mapMin, map2[x][y])
            mapMax = math.max(mapMax, map2[x][y])
        end
    end
    -- /*scale the values between 0 and 255 for rendering in grey 
      scale.*/
    mapMultiplier = 255 / (mapMax - mapMin)
    for x = 400, (mapWidth + 400) do
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            map2[x][y] = map2[x][y] * mapMultiplier
        end
    end
end

function getNoiseValue(x, y, freq, amp)
    return InterpolatedNoise_1(x / freq, y / freq) * amp
end

function love.load()
    love.window.setMode( 1920, 1080, {fullscreen=false})
    getExampleMap()
    getExampleMap2()
end

function love.draw()

    for x = 0, mapWidth - 1 do
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            love.graphics.setColor(map[x][y], map[x][y], map[x][y], 255)
            love.graphics.point(x,y)
        end
    end
    for x = 400, (mapWidth + 400) do
        for y = 0, mapHeight - 1 do
            love.graphics.setColor(map2[x][y], map2[x][y], map2[x][y], 
              255)
            love.graphics.point(x,y)
        end
    end

end

function love.update()

end

function love.keyreleased(key)
    if key == "escape" then
        love.event.quit()
    end
end
```

If I use seed 345 there is no line.

Comment: What line are you talking about, can you show it on the pic?

Comment: You can tell that the left side chunk is slightly darker than the right side chunk.

Comment: @NilsOleTimm To whom are you saying this? I for example can not see any chunk being darker.

Comment: I was talking to you. It is certainly very faint but if you go right down the middle of the picture all of the pixels to the left are darker than all the pixels to the right of the dividing center line. It's possible that I can only see it due to my monitor settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to you scaling the map by your map multiplier. If the difference between the min and max values is different you will scale one sector higher and one lower causing the same noise value to end up as a different actual value.
Instead you should have a global scaling factor that ensures you only ever map stuff to the 0..255 range.